# is there a cleaner way to edit 1 of the 4 CGRect values of a UIView's frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

generally when I want to move a label to the right 20px, or increase just the width of a view, I go through one of the following avenues

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x+20, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
```

or

```
CGRect viewFrame = view.frame;
viewFrame.x += 20;
view.frame = viewFrame;
```

I don't particularly like the amount of code that goes into either variation and was hoping you guys knew a shortcut that I hadn't discovered

Comment: This category is interesting: [UIView+FrameAdditions](https://gist.github.com/nfarina/3412730)

Comment: thanks that looks interesting i'll check that out. i am also hoping to find a macro similar to colinE's answer for adjusting the frame width/height

Comment: There's another good blog here: http://nshipster.com/cggeometry/ For differential shrinking/growing `CGRectInset` would be the transformation to use.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A better method of moving to the right is the `CGRectOffset` macro:

```
label.frame = CGRectOffset(label.frame, 20.0f, 0.0f);
```

I find that this a clearer expression of the intent of my code.

Comment: just read the documentation and that seems terrific for origin changes thank you! is there a macro of this for adjusting just the width height as well?

Comment: No, but there are very useful macros for shrinking / growing a rectangle about its center

Comment: Actually, I think the shrink macro takes separate width and height factors, so may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add:

[Here's](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/cgrect-tricks/)  an article with nice CGRect tricks (Shrinking, Expanding, Edge Insetting, Intersecting)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible I use `center` to modify the origin:

```
myView.center = CGPointMake(150, 150);
```

Or even better:

```
myView.center = anotherView.center;
```

To modify the size `frame` or `bounds` are the only way to go. You can use the various `CGRect` functions in [CGGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html) to express the transformation at a higher level.